# Unresolved reference: viewModelScope

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am tring to use viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) in my android project android studio show the error "Unresolved reference: viewModelScope" I copy pasted the dependency from official site. I also tried to migrate to android x.

I added the latest dependency from official sites also tried Invalide cache and restart yet did'nt work.

My Module level gradle file dependencies

```
 dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

        def room_version = "2.2.0-alpha01" // 2.1.0 for latest stable version

        implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
        annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor

        // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
        implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

        // optional - RxJava support for Room
        implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

        // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
        implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

        // Test helpers
        testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"



        def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"

        // ViewModel and LiveData
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
        // alternatively - just ViewModel
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version" // For Kotlin use lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx
        // alternatively - just LiveData
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
        // alternatively - Lifecycles only (no ViewModel or LiveData). Some UI
        //     AndroidX libraries use this lightweight import for Lifecycle
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"

        annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
        // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

        // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version" // For Kotlin use lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx

        // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
        testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"




    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Lifecycle Release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.1.0-alpha01), the first version of `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` (the correct artifact for ViewModel related Kotlin extensions) that contains `viewModelScope` is `2.1.0-alpha01`. Therefore you should upgrade to the latest version: either `2.1.0-rc01` or `2.2.0-alpha02`, both of which include that API.

Answer (score 1):

The correct dependency for [ViewModel KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#viewmodel) should be `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$version`